# Unable to connect to SQlite using mono

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

In my program I have this simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;

.... 
IDbConnection cnx = new SqliteConnection("URI=file:reestr.db");
cnx.Open();
....
```

And this is how I compile it:

```
$ mcs Test.cs -r:System.Data.dll -r:mono.data.sqliteclient.dll
```

It compiles ok. But when I run it with `./Test.exe`, I get this error messages:

> Missing method .ctor in assembly ....
>   Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Data.SqliteClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
>   File name: 'Mono.Data.SqliteClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and how to repair it.

PS. I'm using Ubuntu as my OS.

Comment: Pheew, it seems like I did it. While this tutorial - http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlite/ - is totally misleading and does not bring the desired result. The key ingredient is to install the right dll. `Mono.Data.SqliteClient.dll` - is not the right one, at least in my case it produces errors. And the right library is `Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `Mono.Data.SqliteClient` can not find the native SQLite binaries:

> Prerequisites If you do not have SQLite, download it. There are
>   binaries for Windows and Linux. You can put the .dll or .so along side
>   your application binaries, or in a system-wide library path.

Ref: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlite/

To obtain pre-compiled native binaries (or source) for your platform:

- http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Also if you have the SQLite native shared libraries installed, are they available via `dlopen`? If not, you can assign the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env. var so Mono can find them at runtime.

> Linux Shared Library Search Path From the dlopen(3) man page, the
>   necessary shared libraries needed by the program are searched for in
>   the following order:
>
> A colon-separated list of directories in the user’s LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   environment variable. This is a frequently-used way to allow native
>   shared libraries to be found by a CLI program. The list of libraries
>   cached in /etc/ld.so.cache. /etc/ld.so.cache is created by editing
>   /etc/ld.so.conf and running ldconfig(8). Editing /etc/ld.so.conf is
>   the preferred way to search additional directories, as opposed to
>   using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as this is more secure (it’s more difficult to
>   get a trojan library into /etc/ld.so.cache than it is to insert it
>   into LD_LIBRARY_PATH). /lib, followed by /usr/lib.

**Ubuntu Notes:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite
$ ls -1  /usr/lib/libsqlite*
/usr/lib/libsqlite.so.0
/usr/lib/libsqlite.so.0.8.6
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ mono ./Test.exe
```

Comment: No, I'm not on Windows. I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have SQLite installed? Try running via `mono --trace ./Test.exe` to see if the SQLite native (`.so`) provider is being found or not.

Comment: Please, pay attention to the fact, that I do not get any errors during  compile time. As I said in my question, I only get error messages when I run my program.

Comment: Yes, I have it installed. I even connected to SQLite in other languages - Java and Python. The problem only with C#

Comment: That is a runtime cmd, not compile: `mono --trace ./Test.exe`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you advise to compile it with this option. So, I've just tried it and got an infinite list of data. It is hardly possible to get something valuable from this

Comment: The only important message I see is `Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Data.SqliteClient`. But it is really interesting since I have this `mono.data.sqliteclient.dll` file with me and compile accordingly with `-r:mono.data.sqliteclient.dll`

Comment: That is a CIL based assembly, not the SQLite native shared library that it depends on.  I updated my answer to include the LD_LIBRARY_PATH info.

Comment: I visited this page - http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki . But it has a dazzling amount of information and archives and I'm not sure what should I download and how should I then compile it on Ubuntu using mono. Still, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I added some Ubuntu steps to the answer, those will ensure the shared library is installed and can be found by mono.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a second. I think the only question that may appear is what api to use. I followed this tutorial - http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlite/

Comment: Still, I cannot solve it. In fact there are several pieces of the problem - 1) `.dll` to download, 2) the way how to compile - something like `-r:blablabla` 3) the right api to use. Now, I cannot make these pieces match together.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem in my Mac in this way. Right Click in Mono.Data.Sqlite on References and click in Local Copy. This make mono copy dll to debug folder and your application will find the library.
OBS: Sorry for my bad english.